# Apply a function to every row of a dataframe and store the data to a list/Dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following simplified version of the code:

```
import pandas as pd


def myFunction(portf, Val):
    mydata = {portf: [Val, Val * 2, Val * 3, Val * 4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns=[portf])
    return df


data = {'Portfolio':  ['Book1', 'Book2', 'Book1', 'Book2'],
        'Value':      [10,      5,       6,       11]}
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Portfolio', 'Value'])

df_output = myFunction(df_input['Portfolio'][0], df_input['Value'][0])
df_output1 = myFunction(df_input['Portfolio'][1], df_input['Value'][1])
df_output2 = myFunction(df_input['Portfolio'][2], df_input['Value'][2])
df_output3 = myFunction(df_input['Portfolio'][3], df_input['Value'][3])
```

What I would like is concatenate all the df_output in a single list or even better in a dataframe in an efficient way as the df_input dataframe will have 100+ columns.

I tried to apply the following:

```
df_input.apply(lambda row : myFunction(row['Portfolio'], row['Value']), axis = 1)
```

However all the results return to a single column.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.concat to store all results in a single dataframe:

```
pd.concat([myFunction(row['Portfolio'], row['Value']) 
           for _, row in df_input.iterrows()], axis=1)
```

First you build a list of pd.DataFrames with a list comprehension (you could also use a normal loop). Then you concat all DataFrames along **axis=1**.

Output:

```
    Book1   Book2   Book1   Book2
0   10      5       6       11
1   20      10      12      22
2   30      15      18      33
3   40      20      24      44
```

You mentioned df_input has many more rows in the original dataframe. To account for this you neeed another loop (minimal example):

```
data = {'Portfolio':  ['Book1', 'Book2', 'Book1', 'Book2'],
        'Value':      [10,      5,       6,       11]}
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Portfolio', 'Value'])
df_input['Value2'] = df_input['Value'] * 100

pd.concat([myFunction(row['Portfolio'], row[col]) 
           for col in df_input.columns if col != 'Portfolio'
           for (_, row) in df_input.iterrows()], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Book1   Book2   Book1   Book2   Book1   Book2   Book1   Book2
0   10      5       6       11      1000    500     600     1100
1   20      10      12      22      2000    1000    1200    2200
2   30      15      18      33      3000    1500    1800    3300
3   40      20      24      44      4000    2000    2400    4400
```

You might want to rename the columns or aggregate the resulting dataframe in some other way. But for this I had to guess (and I try not to guess in the face of ambiguity).